# Send post request with foreign key - controller set null for foreign data

Tags: c#, .net, angular

When I send from Microsoft sql server to database then work fine. 
But, when send post request from postman or angular, foreign data always is null.
I don't know where is problem.
 This is class:

```
public class Korpa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_korisnika { get; set; }
    public Korisnik Korisnik { get; set; }
    public int Id_Artikla { get; set; }
    public Artikal Artikal { get; set; }

}
public class Artikal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite naziv grupe artikla!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Grupa { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite ime artikla!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Naziv_artikla { get; set; }
    public decimal? Nabavna_cena { get; set; }
    public decimal? Prodajna_cena { get; set; }
    public short? kolicina { get; set; }
    public string url_slike { get; set; }
    public string Specifikacija { get; set; }
}
public class Korisnik
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite vase ime!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Ime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite vase prezime!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Prezime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite korisnicko ime!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite sifru!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Sifra { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite email")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite vasu adresu!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Adresa { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite vas broj telefona!")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Broj_telefona { get; set; }
    public string jmbg { get; set; }
    public int Nivo { get; set; }
}
```

This cotroller:

```
    // GET: api/Korpas/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Korpa))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetKorpa(int id)
    {
        var korpa = db.Korpa
            .Include(c => c.Korisnik)
            .Include(c => c.Artikal)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        if (korpa == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(korpa);
    }


    // POST: api/Korpas
    [ResponseType(typeof(Korpa))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostKorpa(Korpa korpa)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Korpa.Add(korpa);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = korpa.Id }, korpa);
    }
```

[Where is null, this send data from post request, where is not, then send sql query from ms sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJaFT.png)

Comment: How do you send POST? what is the content type? I think you might be missing [FromForm] or [FromBody] attributes before Korpa parameter

Comment: Post from postman: 
{
    "Id_korisnika": 2,
    "Korisnik_Id": 2,
    "Id_Artikla": 3,
    "Artikal_Id":  3
}
from angular:this.http.post('https://webecangular.azurewebsites.net/api/korpas',
     JSON.stringify({
      Id_korisnika: 2,
      Korisnik_Id: 2,
      Id_Artikla: 10,
      Artikal_Id: 10
    }),
    this.options
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.getUsrData = data;
    });
options = {
    headers: {'content-type' : ['application/json']}
  };

Comment: Please provide request body and headers of your request

Comment: Header is content-type, value application/json
Body: 
{ 
"Id_korisnika": 2,
"Korisnik_Id": 2,
"Id_Artikla": 3,
"Artikal_Id":  3
}

Comment: You are posting object of type `Korpa` but it has no properties `Artikal_Id` and `Korisnik_Id`. So you have to post entire tree of objects

Comment: I know. But how resolve this ? Change class Korpa or post in controller Korpas?

Comment: it depends if you want to save child objects as well. If yes, you need to provide child objects as part of request, if no, you should modify Korpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

```
public class Korpa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_korisnika { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id_korisnika")]
    public Korisnik Korisnik { get; set; }
    public int Id_Artikla { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id_Artikla")]
    public Artikal Artikal { get; set; }
}
```

Just add [ForeignKey("name of foreign key")]

Answer (score 0):

Your POST method receives a Korpa model, but the entity does not have the **Artikal_Id** property, you must add the property to the Korpa model so that the web api can perform the serialization.

```
public class Korpa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id_korisnika { get; set; }
    public Korisnik Korisnik { get; set; }
    public int Id_Artikla { get; set; }
    public Artikal Artikal { get; set; }
    public int Artikal_Id {get; set;} // Add this property

}
```

Comment: Do I have create migration and update database after I add this property ?

Comment: @A.Demir if you are using entity framework, maybe if you have to do the update

Comment: It doesn't work. When update database, entity framework change name of property Artikal_Id to Artikal_Id_Id in database. Without update database, controller have error...

Comment: you already have real data in the Korpa table ?, because you could delete the table and let the Entity Framework create the table again based on the properties of the Korpa model, maybe the Entity Framework changes the name of the Artikal_Id property to Artikal_Id_Id because the table already has the property Artikal_Id